# How to set option value according to my ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, select

I have an html having select options there. by default there is default value is selected like first option.
somewhere I request ajax request to get value for that select options.
I got it 3(e.g.) I do something using Jquery but value is not getting updated.
here is my snippet.

**HTML code**

```
<select class="form-control custom-form-control font-16 table-form-control" id="edit_merchant_id">
    <option value="">Select Merchant</option>
        <option value="1" merchantname="Yoox.com">Yoox.com</option>
        <option value="2" merchantname="Best Buy">Best Buy</option>
        <option value="3" merchantname="Walmart">Walmart</option>
        <option value="4" merchantname="Lane Bryant">Lane Bryant</option>
        <option value="5" merchantname="Reebok">Reebok</option>
        <option value="6" merchantname="adidas">adidas</option>
        <option value="7" merchantname="Urban Outfitters">Urban Outfitters</option>
</select>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$("#edit_merchant_id select").val(parseInt(response.merchant_id));
```

Comment: looking at you html, your jQuery should be: $("#edit_merchant_id").val(response.merchant_id); //no int conversion requred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is not correct `$("#edit_merchant_id select")` replace with `$("#edit_merchant_id")`

```js
var response = {};
response.merchant_id = 5;
$("#edit_merchant_id").val(response.merchant_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control custom-form-control font-16 table-form-control" id="edit_merchant_id">
    <option value="">Select Merchant</option>
        <option value="1" merchantname="Yoox.com">Yoox.com</option>
        <option value="2" merchantname="Best Buy">Best Buy</option>
        <option value="3" merchantname="Walmart">Walmart</option>
        <option value="4" merchantname="Lane Bryant">Lane Bryant</option>
        <option value="5" merchantname="Reebok">Reebok</option>
        <option value="6" merchantname="adidas">adidas</option>
        <option value="7" merchantname="Urban Outfitters">Urban Outfitters</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

This will select the select the `select` & `option` & will update selected option

```
$('#edit_merchant_id option[value="3"]').attr('selected', 'selected')
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/s44Lmwxk/)